# .NET 2.0 issue with assembly not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, asmx, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

i have to fight against a strange issue in my company. we have 2 .net 2.0 (old, i know) apps, which start with an .asmx-file. the code-behind calls a c#-file, which includes a `include abcd` directive, whereby `abcd` originates from a 3rd-party company.

one app is in test and it works fine. the identical one is in production and fails with the error *Could not load file or assembly 'abcd.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.*

when i look in the related web.config-files, none of them includes a pointer to abcd.dll, which i first do not understand in the context of the productive environment, where everything works. secondly when i look inside the \bin-folder, i see the related assembly/dll. again: this is identical in both systems.

the only difference of both systems is the fact that visual studio 2.0 (does this really exist?) is available on the test system.

please note: i am aware that assemblies have to be added via solution explorer in visual studio too. but i cannot do this as such an installation is not allowed  here. but again: in web.config on the test server no reference can be found in the related web.config and everythings works fine.

so my question is: how to get this thing working in productive env?

thanks in advance

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to run Dependency Walker (depends.exe) http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and point it at to detect if any dependencies are missing.

I'd also look in the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly) to see if there are any related differences there.

Also, compare IIS setting on the two machines.